# jQuery : Move each label text content to it's associated select option with selected=selected attribute

Tags: jquery, forms, label, html-select

I'm a jQuery beginner and here's what I want to do :

I have a form containing two `<select>` controls. Each of them has a different `<label>`.
I need to move the text content of each `<label>` to the first `<option>` (`<option value="" selected="selected">`) of it's associated `<select>`.

Here's my jQuery :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    var CONTACT_FILTER_LABEL = jQuery(".contact-filter option:selected").closest("label").text();

    jQuery(".contact-filter option:selected").each(function(){
        jQuery(this).html(CONTACT_FILTER_LABEL);
    });    
});
```

I guess that I also need to fill the value attribute of the `<option>` control with the same content. I tried a whole lot of things but couldn't make it yet.

jsFiddle link (UPDATED!) : http://jsfiddle.net/y9JaE/27/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(function() {
    $("select").each(function() {
        var text = $(this).prev("label").text();
        $(this).children("option[selected='selected']").val(text).text(text);
    });
});​
```

[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y9JaE/29/)

Obviously your jQuery selectors will vary depending on the structure/css classes you use, as will you have to decide on the best of `.siblings()`, `.closest()` etc depending on tag structure.

Comment: Thank you Anders. For some reason, my jsFiddle link missed a bunch of code so I had to update it. You code is working for one label/select, but I need the JS to work for several labels/selects... But this is only because you worked on the wrong code snippet. I apologize for this. Thank you for helping me out !

Comment: My code will work on all `select` elements on a page. The `.each(...)` function creates a loop that operates on all the elements selected with the previous jQuery selector. I had to do some minor changes because of the HTML structure you have chosen, so check out my code/fiddle again.